# Shared printer disappeared from LAN

Tags: windows, printer

I have a printer connected to a windows XP PC. It is shared on the network. Yesterday it could be used by the households two other computers. Today it has disappeared from the network.
It works perfectly on the pc it's connected to.

I cant find it when browsing shared printers nor connect to it using the name it's name like this:

> \\ComputerName\printername

I tried turning off sharing and turn it on again restarting the computer.

What else can I try?

Comment: Can you ping the computer by IP address?

Comment: Answer it yourself - you solved it :)

Comment: You're allowed to answer your own question - you may earn the "Scholar" badge doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out it was not a windows problem at all, it was a router problem. Very, very rarely my router stops routing between the wlan and the lan part and the comments made me remember this.

I feel a bit stupid for not noticing that neither the fileshare nor ping could reach the computer.

Things I tried before I realized I was being stupid.

- Verified that File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks is Installed
- Checked that file and printer sharing was allowed in windows firewall